# Mix up with my styling

Tags: css

I'm in a bit of a mix up with my styling would like some assistance specifically with getting my page_content_div to appear under my header as opposed to under the right and left carousel controls. Applying float left on the page_content_div didn't help. I've also placed the code jsfiddle and the outcome is pretty much the same.

I suspect its a basic oversight on my part but can anyone spot any errors I'm making in the header or container_div CSS?

Here's a screenshot of my current index.html code:

[image: mix up with divs]

Here's my index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/public.css">

   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.css"> -->

   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.6.0/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css&2.6.0/build/base/base-min.css">

   <link href="stylesheets/carouseltwo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="stylesheets/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

   <title>Welcome</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="topbar">
        <a class="logo_link" href="http://www.swim-mates.com/learning/landingpage/index.html">Logo text</a>

        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'><span>MENU OPTION A</span></a></li>
           <li ><a href='#'><span>MENU OPTION B</span></a></li>
           <li ><a href='#'><span>MENU OPTION C</span></a></li>
           <li ><a href='#'><span>MENU OPTION D</span></a></li>                        
        </ul>           
    </div>

    <!-- Welcome message -->
    <div class="welcome_message">
        Welcome message ... Welcome message ... Welcome message ... Welcome message ...
    </div>

    <!-- Header Carousel -->
    <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');">

                </div>

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption A</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');">

                </div>

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption B</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');">

                </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption C</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>

        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>

    </header>       

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page_content" class="page_content_div">

        <div class="row_div">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">
                    Sign up
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Call to Action Section -->
        <div class="well">
            <div class="row">

            </div>
        </div> 

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row_div">
                <div class="footer_div">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Desired footer text 2014</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>           
    </div>      

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
    <script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 2000 //changes the speed
    })
    </script>       
</body>

</html>
```

Here's my public.css:

```
    html {height: 100%; width: 100%;}

body {
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    border: 0;
    font-family: "DINPro-Bold",Georgia,Serif;    
    font-size: 15px; 
    line-height: 15px;
}

/* Main div - this will hold all the componenets*/
.main_div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;  
}

/* Welcome message div*/
.logo_link {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-family: "DINPro-Bold",Georgia,Serif;
  background-color: #FFCC00; 
}

/* Top bar*/
#topbar {
  background: #3399CC;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px #808080;
  float: left;
}

/* ul */
#topbar ul {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  zoom: 1;
}

/* li */
#topbar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Insert a gap after every <ul> element */
#topbar ul:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* ul li a */
#topbar ul li a {
  font-family: "DINPro-Bold",Georgia,Serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s;
  -moz-transition: color .25s;
  -ms-transition: color .25s;
  -o-transition: color .25s;
  transition: color .25s;  
}

/* ul li a:hover */
#topbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

/* Bullet point after the menu name */
#topbar ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 19px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: .5;
}

/* Insert content before every <a> element's content */
#topbar ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: #00FF00;
  -webkit-transition: width .25s;
  -moz-transition: width .25s;
  -ms-transition: width .25s;
  -o-transition: width .25s;
  transition: width .25s;
}

#topbar ul li.last > a:after,
#topbar ul li:last-child > a:after {
  display: none;
}

#topbar ul li.active a {
  color: #FFDD00;
}

#topbar ul li.active a:before {
  width: 100%;
}

#topbar.align-right li.last > a:after,
#topbar.align-right li:last-child > a:after {
  display: block;
}

#topbar.align-right li:first-child a:after {
  display: none;
}

/*Overall/Super div*/
.main_div {
  width: 100%;  
  float: left;
  font-family: "DINPro-Bold",Georgia,Serif; 
}

/* Welcome message div*/
.welcome_message {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 25px;  
  float: left;
  color: #999999;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* */
.page_content_div {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color:#FFCC00;
}

/* row div */
.row_div {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  background-color:#99FF99;
  font-family: "DINPro-Bold",Georgia,Serif; 
}

/* footer inner div */
.footer_div {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background-color:#FF0000;
}

/* Carousel arrows/control 
.arrows {
  position:relative;
  background-color:#99FF99;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:15%;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:center;
  text-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(255,114,0,.6);
  filter:alpha(opacity=50);opacity:.5;
}

.arrows.left{
  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 100%);
  background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 100%);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,from(rgba(0,0,0,.5)),to(rgba(0,0,0,.0001)));
  background-image:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 100%);
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
  background-repeat:repeat-x
}

.arrows.right{
  right:0;
  left:auto;
  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
  background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,from(rgba(0,0,0,.0001)),to(rgba(0,0,0,.5)));
  background-image:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
  background-repeat:repeat-x
}
*/
```

Here's my modern-business.css:

```
    /*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Modern Business HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

/* Global Styles */

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    /* padding-top: 50px;  Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
}

.img-portfolio {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.img-hover:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Home Page Carousel */

header.carousel {
    height: 50%;
}

header.carousel .item,
header.carousel .item.active,
header.carousel .carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}

header.carousel .fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

/* 404 Page Styles */

.error-404 {
    font-size: 100px;
}

/* Pricing Page Styles */

.price {
    display: block;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.price sup {
    top: -20px;
    left: 2px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.period {
    display: block;
    font-style: italic;
}

/* Footer Styles */

footer {
    /*margin: 50px 0;*/
}

/* Responsive Styles */

@media(max-width:991px) {
    .customer-img,
    .img-related {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
    .img-portfolio {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    header.carousel .carousel {
        height: 70%;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: So where is the JSFiddle?

Comment: and... you can't just move the html block?

Comment: Could you make a reduced code example that reproduces the problem? Right now you have too much code to easily look thru.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step in the right direction. Still a lot of clean up to do. But now you have your divs not overlaying each other, but appearing one after the other. Hope that helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/marineboudeau/02wsoh42/1/

Amongst other things, I've centered your page_content_div on the page by adding a margin left/right: auto and adding a width to it (if you want it to span across the page, just make that width 100%). 
I've also added a `clear:both`.

```
.page_content_div {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: #FFCC00;
  width: 800px;
  clear: both;
}
```